# Issue compiling sass file

Tags: ruby, extjs, themes, sass

I am using senhca touch for development. I know that sass is used for customising the themes in sencha touch. I installed the required material, but when I compile the scss file, it gives the error:

```
You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory.
```

I am confused. Can anyone help me? I tried to compile by giving the full path, but it is still not working.
Config =.rb is as follows ..

```
 # Get the directory that this configuration file exists in
 dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
 # Load the sencha-touch framework automatically.
 load File.join(dir, '..', 'themes')
 # Compass configurations
 sass_path    = dir
 css_path     = File.join(dir, "..", "css")
 environment  = :production
 output_style = :compressed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `config.rb`, the filepaths for `css_dir`, `sass_dir`  etc are needed to be relative to the folder `config.rb` lives in.  see if you have this problem

Comment: # Get the directory that this configuration file exists in
dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)

# Load the sencha-touch framework automatically.
load File.join(dir, '..', 'themes')

# Compass configurations
sass_path    = dir
css_path     = File.join(dir, "..", "css")
environment  = :production
output_style = :compressed

Comment: Config.rb is something like this

Comment: Well i have searched it and find the same answer but kindly tell me how to change this